# Добавление новых элементов на странице, используя Хуки

Tags: reactjs

Имеется вот такой хук

```html
    const Education = [];
    Education.push(obl);
    Education.push(obl);
    const [SS, setCurrentSS] = useState(Education);
```

obl - это объект с набором полей div.

Отображение SS происходит так

```html
        <div id="ObrazovanieSetting">
         {SS}
            <div role="button" className="mer_button" onClick={AddObr}>
             <span>Добавить</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку Добавить, вызывается функция AddObr

```html
const AddObr = () => {
    setCurrentSS(SS.push(obl));
};
```

React пишет "TypeError: SS.push is not a function"
Как заставить хук понять что это массив, или какой альтернативный вариант для добавления элемента можно использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хук состояния(state) нельзя обновлять пушем. Сначала разворачиваем старое значение, потом записываем новое.

```js
setCurrentSS([...SS, newItem])
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем, данный код сработал:

```html
setCurrentSS((previewQ) => { Education.push(obl); previewQ = Education; return previewQ; });
```

Но хук не вызывал обновление рендера, и данную проблему я решил грубым способом - добавил хук counter, и при добавлении элемента в setCurrentSS я обновляю и counter, который уже без проблем вызывает рендер.